# How to write an nt:file programmatically

Tags: aem, jcr

I'm trying to store binary data in JCR, which is created on the fly. My problem is that the only way provided by the JCR API is via an `InputStream`:

```
Session session = request.getResourceResolver().adaptTo(Session.class);
ValueFactory valueFactory = session.getValueFactory();
Binary bin = valueFactory.createBinary(is);
```

As CQ/Sling is RESTful I can see why this is the case as you usually get a form post or an httprequest to another source, where you always have an `InputStream` to use. But in my case I am creating the binary on the fly which usually is represented as an `OutputStream`.

1. Is there any other way I overlooked in the JCR API where I could create an `OutputStream` directly on the nt:file node, just like a `FileOutputStream`?
2. If no, is there an easy way to have an `OutpuStream` transformed to an `InputStream`?

I know the other way is available from the Apache Commons `IOUtils.copy()`. I've seen some examples on SO where they just use the `ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()` to create an `InputStream`. But as the data could get rather large, this is not a good solution. Besides I tried it and somehow the stream was incomplete, so it seems there is a buffer limmit. The next approach was with piped streams, but there I have other problems to which I opened another question: [Multiple quotes cause PipedOutputStream/OutputStreamWriter to fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27171638/multiple-quotes-cause-pipedoutputstream-outputstreamwriter-to-fail)

EDIT:
Removed PipedStream code example as I posted the issue with it in another question. So here I am still just looking for an easy way to create an nt:file where the input is not an `InputStream`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pipes are good solution here. However, in order to implement them properly, you have to use two threads: first should write data into the `PipedOutputStream` and the second should create a `Binary` from `PipedInputStream` and save it into JCR:

```
final PipedInputStream pis = new PipedInputStream();
final PipedOutputStream pos = new PipedOutputStream(pis);
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(new Runnable() {         
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(pos);
            writer.append("append here some data");
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
Binary binary = session.getValueFactory().createBinary(pis);
session.getNode("/content/myNode").setProperty("xyz", binary);
session.save();
```

The symmetrical solution, in which you handle the JCR in the new thread would be also good.

Comment: Thanks for the code example. I tried it in a unit test using IOUtils.toString() and it worked. Now I need to try it in CQ.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried on of the methods described here?

http://ostermiller.org/convert_java_outputstream_inputstream.html

I think the easiest methods would be using an array:

```
  ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
  //alternatively, get the outputstream of your binary file generator
  (...) //put data into out
  InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray())
```

Comment: I tried that at first, but the result is an incomplete Binary in JCR