# Multiple quotes cause PipedOutputStream/OutputStreamWriter to fail

Tags: java, stream

I stumbled over a very strange behavior with the `PipedOutputStream` when I was trying to copy an `OutputStream` to an `InputStream`. See also [How to write an nt:file programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27170741/how-to-write-an-ntfile-programmatically)

Here is a small unit test method:

```
@Test
public void pipeTest() {
    PipedInputStream pin = null;
    try {
        pin = new PipedInputStream();
        PipedOutputStream pout = new PipedOutputStream(pin);
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(pout);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            writer.write("\"Test\";" + i + "\n");
            // writer.write("\"Test\";" + "\"" + i + "\"\n");
        }

        writer.close();
        pout.close();

        System.out.print(IOUtils.toString(pin));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.print(e);
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(pin);
    }

}
```

This works well and prints out 100 rows. If you uncomment the second write statement and comment out the first, `writer.close()` gets stuck and never finishes. It seems to have problem with the second set of quotes `\"`.
Has anyone and idea why this is the case and how to circumvent it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the quotes - and everything to do with how much data you're writing. To demonstrate this, you can get rid of the writer and the loop entirely, and just use:

```
pout.write(new byte[1024]);
```

Or keep your existing code, but see that this works (because it writes 1000 bytes):

```
writer.write("0123456789");
```

but this doesn't (because it tries to write 1100 bytes):

```
writer.write("0123456789X");
```

That works - but if you change it to 1025, it'll hang forever... because the internal buffer is 1024 bytes long by default, and nothing's consuming the stream. (You're not reading from `pin` until you've finished writing.) As nothing is consuming any of the first 1024 bytes, there's nowhere to put the 1025th byte, so `write` blocks until there *is* space.

You could:

- Change the pipe size when you construct the `PipedInputStream`, so it's got a bigger buffer
- Read from the pipe while you're writing - e.g. in a separate thread.

Comment: Thanks for the very fast answer. Do you have any idea how else I could solve my problem with copying the output to the input stream?

Comment: @Thomas: I don't see what you mean - the whole point of a pipe is that it *does* copy the output to the input stream. You could no doubt use `IOUtils.toString` in a different thread and that would work - or you could increase the pipe size. Basically the suggestions at the bottom of the answer :)

Comment: I can give it a try, but combined with my initial problem in JCR, I don't think I will be able to have two threads. JCR is transaction based so the InputStream will probably only be consumed when I make a session.save();

Comment: @Thomas: Looking at your previous question, it seems that you don't want to have all the data in memory - which means *something* needs to be consuming it as you write. If that's the case, `Piped*Stream` is your friend. If that's not the case, just use `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

A `PipedInputStream` has an internal buffer. By default the buffer is 1024 bytes, but you can pass a different size to the constructor of `PipedInputStream`.

When the buffer is full, a write the the `PipedOutputStream` that's associated with the `PipedInputStream` blocks until you have read enough data from the latter, so that there is space in the buffer.

Your problem is unrelated to the double quotes itself; it's just that you write more data when you add the double quotes.

You should only use the piped stream in multi-threaded code (in which one thread writes to the piped output stream, and another thread reads from the piped input stream), to avoid this possible deadlock.

The Javadoc for `PipedInputStream` has a clear warning about this:

> Attempting to use both objects from a single thread is not
>   recommended, as it may deadlock the thread.